# Syntax on printing objects?

Tags: java, syntax

Directions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWdQ2.jpg

I don't think I am printing out the objects correctly. My teacher helped me with the first part so I believe I am assigning them correctly. When printing them out, do I use "this" command? What is the right syntax for this type of situation?

Thank you.

```
public static void main(String [ ] args) {

 Dog1 Rover = new Dog1("Rover", 4);
 Sheep1 Wooly = new Sheep1("Wooly", 4);
 Duck1 Daffy = new Duck1("Daffy", 2);
 Cat1 Ketty = new Cat1("Ketty", 4);

 System.out.println(name.Dog1, getHello.Dog1, isCarnivorous.Dog1, isMammal.Dog1);
 System.out.println(name.Sheep1, getHello.Sheep1, isCarnivorous.Sheep1, isMammal.Sheep1);
 System.out.println(name.Duck1, getHello.Duck1, isCarnivorous.Duck1, isMammal.Duck1);
 System.out.println(name.Cat11, getHello.Cat1, isCarnivorous.Cat1, isMammal.Cat1);

}
```

Updated:

```
public abstract class Animal1 { //creating Animal1 which is the base and parent class, it is abstract so abstract classes can be created below

    private String animalName; //defining animalName as private 
    public int numberOfLegs; //# of legs as public 

public Animal1(final String name){ //first constructor with only assigning name 

        animalName = name;
} 

public Animal1(final String name, final int legs){ //second constructor assigning both name and number of legs

        animalName = name;
        numberOfLegs = legs;
}


public String getName(){ //first getMethod for animalName
        return animalName;
}


public int getLegs(){ //second getMethod for returning numberOfLegs
        return numberOfLegs;
}


public boolean isMammal(){ //returning true value with boolean
        return true;
}


public boolean isCarnivorous(){ //returning true value with boolean
        return true;
}


public abstract String getHello(); //creating an abstract method, possible because base class is also abstract

}


public class Cat1 extends Animal1{ //child class of Animal1

    public Cat1(final String name){ //Creating class constructor taking a name, within the constructor call the parent class constructor taking one argument
        super(name, 4); 
 }

    @Override
    public String getHello(){  //Overriding getHello to return "Meow" 
        return "Meow";
 }
}

public class Dog1 extends Animal1{ //another child of Dog1

    public Dog1(final String name){ //Creating class constructor taking a name, within the constructor call the parent class constructor taking one argument
        super(name, 4);
     }

    @Override
    public String getHello(){ //Overriding getHello to return "Woof"
        return "Woof";
     }
}

public class Duck1 extends Animal1{ //third child class of Animal1

    public Duck1(final String name){ //Creating class constructor taking a name, within the constructor call the parent class constructor taking one argument
        super(name, 2);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean isMammal(){ //Overriding isMammal() function to return false, as a duck is not a mammal 
        return false;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean isCarnivorous(){ //Overriding isCarnivorous() function to return false as a duck is not a carnivore
        return false;
     }

    @Override
    public String getHello(){ //Overriding getHello to return "Quack"
        return "Quack";
     }

}

public class Sheep1 extends Animal1{ //fourth child class of Animal1

    public Duck1(final String name){ //Creating class constructor taking a name, within the constructor call the parent class constructor taking one argument
        super(name, 2);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean isCarnivorous(){ //Overriding isCarnivorous() function to return false as a sheep is not a carnivore
        return false;
     }

    @Override
    public String getHello(){ //Overriding getHello to return "Baa"
        return "Baa";
     }

}

public static void main(String [ ] args) {

 Dog1 Rover = new Dog1("Rover", 4);
 Sheep1 Wooly = new Sheep1("Wooly", 4);
 Duck1 Daffy = new Duck1("Daffy", 2);
 Cat1 Ketty = new Cat1("Ketty", 4);

System.out.println(Rover.getName() + ", " + Rover.getHello() + ", " + Rover.isCarnivorous() + ", " + Rover.isMammal());
System.out.println(Wooly.getName() + ", " + Wooly.getHello() + ", " + Wooly.isCarnivorous() + ", " + Wooly.isMammal());
System.out.println(Daffy.getName() + ", " + Daffy.getHello() + ", " + Daffy.isCarnivorous() + ", " + Daffy.isMammal());
System.out.println(Ketty.getName() + ", " + Ketty.getHello() + ", " + Ketty.isCarnivorous() + ", " + Ketty.isMammal());

}
```

Comment: Post your `Dog1` class.

Comment: "I don't think I am printing out the objects correctly." - Sure you do! **Run it.** Does it work? You're doing it right! Does it not work? Ask yourself, "why?"

Comment: @shmosel I ended up editing and posting the whole thing. Could you take a look?

Comment: You seem to have updated the post with your fixed code: Are you still having a problem with it? Does it work?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: I'd rather not have my projects posted once they are fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDoe9292 you would rather not like it but, people can still go in edit history and view your `PROJECTS`!

Comment: @JohnDoe9292 That's not how it works. SO is not a support desk. It's to gather a repository of knowledge. Once you've posted a question, it's here for good, to help others out in the future who may have similar problems. If your problem has been solved, please mark the answer which solved it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to refer to the variable by name, not by class. And the method comes after the object. And `System.out.println()` doesn't accept multiple arguments. Try this:

```
System.out.println(Rover.getName() + ", " + Rover.getHello() + ", " + Rover.isCarnivorous() + ", " + Rover.isMammal());
```

Similarly for the other lines.

Comment: `getHello` is most likely a method, so should be `getHello()`

Comment: @Blorgbeard you're probably right, but it's not clear in the question and `name` sounds more like a field.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this. I looked back and all are methods, even name. It should have been getName.

Comment: @JohnDoe9292 updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your syntax reversed. If these are all methods that you're calling, then they're done like `Dog1.name()`. <strike>If they're just public variables, you can call them like `Dog1.name`.</strike>

Also, a word of advice - most object instants in java follow the syntax of first word lowercase, following words uppercase (like your methods). Not crucial, but helpful to know.

Edit: Yep, it's just what the first line of this answer reads. To get the boolean from your animal class, just call them with first the object's name, then `.exampleMethod()`.

Also, for your print statements, the println method might print the statements funny if you leave it as it is. What you can do instead is just add some strings in between like so:

```
System.out.println("Name: " + Dog1.getName() + ", Hello: " + Dog1.getHello()...); // rest of line excluded for brevity
```

Comment: I updated the main post with the entire program. Could you take a look? thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword this refers to the current object.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dog1 dog = new Dog1("Rover", 4);

        System.out.println(dog.name() + " " + dog.hello() + " " + dog.carnivorus() + " " + dog.mammal() + "."); 
    }

}

class Dog1
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String hello;
    private boolean carnivorus;
    private boolean mammal;

    public Dog1(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.hello = "woof woof";
        this.carnivorus = true;
        this.mammal = true;
    }

    public String name()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String hello()
    {
        return this.hello;
    }

    public boolean carnivorus()
    {
        return this.carnivorus;
    }

    public boolean mammal()
    {
        return this.mammal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the post with the entire program. They look very similar but without this. Did I do it correctly?